# civicrm.org website old what/whatiscivicrm redirect to explore-civicrm

Tags: wordpress, webserver, 4.4

I am using my older, ancient 4.4.5 wordpress version of civicrm (I am about to upgrade it) but I think this link is hard coded. In my site when going to the menu Help...About it links to

https://civicrm.org/what/whatiscivicrm

I get "page not found". To make the user experience of all old civicrm installations one step better and not make them take the time to look for an updated link like I had to do I think it should redirect to

https://civicrm.org/explore-civicrm

I believe https://issues.civicrm.org is where this needs to get reported eventually but I wanted to ask here first.

What next step can people recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added this redirect, thanks for reporting it!

I think it's great you've made the effort to post it somewhere we can field it, and that the end result is more important than correct process - so don't fret about not posting it on issues.civicrm.org this time. Thanks for being part of the community! You did this to benefit others in your situation, knowing you wouldn't benefit yourself, and that's priceless.

Your next step is to finish that upgrade of your old CiviCRM to a supported release ASAP

Hop on over to https://chat.civicrm.org to discuss.